# 3D to 2D array in 1 code line

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array: 25x30000x139
I want it to be 2D like this:

```
  (SSSSSSS, 25)  --SSSSSS is a number--
```

This is my code:

```
  y = x3D.swapaxes(0,2)             
  z = y.swapaxes(1,2)               
  x2D = np.reshape(z.shape[1],-1)
```

These are the outputs:

```
   (25, 30000, 139)
   (139, 25, 30000)
   (1, )
```

What am I doing wrong? Why I do not get the (SSSSSS, 25) array?
Is there a way to do it in 1 line?
I tried:

```
    x2D = np.swapaxes((np.swapaxes(x3D,0,2),1,2).reshape(x3D.shape[1],-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
    np.swapaxes(x3D.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(x3D.shape[0], -1), 0,1)
```

From 3D: (25, 30000, 139)

To 2D: (4170000, 25)

in 1 line!!!!  :)